# Connecting Testlink with Gmail SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, testlink

so this is my first time asking here. I have been trying to enable any SMTP for my company's Testlink. However, I cant figure out why I cant manage to make it work since 8 hours ago. been spending my office hours trying to solve this problem and googling there and here but sadly, it seems like none of the solution works for me. if  anyone could please kindly revise my code, I would be glad to have your kind help.

the error mostly about:

```html
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server:
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server:
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedSMTP Error: Could not authenticate. PROBLEMS SENDING MAIL TO: sapurabugzilla@gmail.com
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

and most of the time it showed it cannot load TLS string.

here is my config.inc.php file :

```html
/* [SMTP] */

/**
 * @var string SMTP server name or IP address ("localhost" should work in the most cases)
 * Configure using custom_config.inc.php
 * @uses lib/functions/email_api.php
 */


// SMTP server Configuration ("localhost" is enough in the most cases)
$g_smtp_host        = 'smtp.gmail.com:465';  # SMTP server MUST BE configured  

# Configure using custom_config.inc.php
$g_tl_admin_email     = 'sapuratestlink@gmail.com'; # for problem/error notification
$g_from_email         = 'sapuratestlink@gmail.com';  # email sender
$g_return_path_email  = 'sapuratestlink@gmail.com';

# Urgent = 1, Not Urgent = 5, Disable = 0
$g_mail_priority = 5;   

/**
 * Taken from mantis for phpmailer config
 * select the method to mail by:
 * PHPMAILER_METHOD_MAIL - mail()
 * PHPMAILER_METHOD_SENDMAIL - sendmail
 * PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP - SMTP
 */
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;

/** Configure only if SMTP server requires authentication */
$g_smtp_username    = 'sapuratestlink@gmail.com';  # user
$g_smtp_password    = 'xxxxxxxx';  # password

/**
 * This control the connection mode to SMTP server. 
 * Can be '', 'ssl','tls'
 * @global string $g_smtp_connection_mode
 */
$g_smtp_connection_mode = '';

/**
 * The smtp port to use.  The typical SMTP ports are 25 and 587.  The port to use
 * will depend on the SMTP server configuration and hence others may be used.
 * @global int $g_smtp_port
 */
$g_smtp_port = 465;
```

class.phpmailer.php file:

```html
/**
   * Sets the Sender email (Return-Path) of the message.  If not empty,
   * will be sent via -f to sendmail or as 'MAIL FROM' in smtp mode.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Sender            = 'sapuratestlink@gmail.com';

  /**
   * Sets the Subject of the message.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Subject           = '';

  /**
   * Sets the Body of the message.  This can be either an HTML or text body.
   * If HTML then run IsHTML(true).
   * @var string
   */
  public $Body              = '';

  /**
   * Sets the text-only body of the message.  This automatically sets the
   * email to multipart/alternative.  This body can be read by mail
   * clients that do not have HTML email capability such as mutt. Clients
   * that can read HTML will view the normal Body.
   * @var string
   */
  public $AltBody           = '';

  /**
   * Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of
   * characters.
   * @var int
   */
  public $WordWrap          = 0;

  /**
   * Method to send mail: ("mail", "sendmail", or "smtp").
   * @var string
   */
  public $Mailer            = 'smtp';

  /**
   * Sets the path of the sendmail program.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Sendmail          = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

  /**
   * Path to PHPMailer plugins.  Useful if the SMTP class
   * is in a different directory than the PHP include path.
   * @var string
   */
  public $PluginDir         = '';

  /**
   * Sets the email address that a reading confirmation will be sent.
   * @var string
   */
  public $ConfirmReadingTo  = 'sapuratestlink@gmail.com';

  /**
   * Sets the hostname to use in Message-Id and Received headers
   * and as default HELO string. If empty, the value returned
   * by SERVER_NAME is used or 'localhost.localdomain'.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Hostname          = '';

  /**
   * Sets the message ID to be used in the Message-Id header.
   * If empty, a unique id will be generated.
   * @var string
   */
  public $MessageID         = '';

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // PROPERTIES FOR SMTP
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /**
   * Sets the SMTP hosts.  All hosts must be separated by a
   * semicolon.  You can also specify a different port
   * for each host by using this format: [hostname:port]
   * (e.g. "smtp1.example.com:25;smtp2.example.com").
   * Hosts will be tried in order.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Host          = 'smtp.gmail.com:465';

  /**
   * Sets the default SMTP server port.
   * @var int
   */
  public $Port          = 465;

  /**
   * Sets the SMTP HELO of the message (Default is $Hostname).
   * @var string
   */
  public $Helo          = 'Hi from Admin Testlink';

  /**
   * Sets connection prefix.
   * Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
   * @var string
   */
  // public $SMTPSecure    = 'tls';

  /**
   * Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables.
   * @var bool
   */
  public $SMTPAuth      = true;

  /**
   * Sets SMTP username.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Username      = 'sapuratestlink@gmail.com';

  /**
   * Sets SMTP password.
   * @var string
   */
  public $Password      = 'xxxxx';

  /**
   * Sets the SMTP server timeout in seconds.
   * This function will not work with the win32 version.
   * @var int
   */
  public $Timeout       = 10;

  /**
   * Sets SMTP class debugging on or off.
   * @var bool
   */
  public $SMTPDebug     = true;

  /**
```

please help me if you're free ! thank you.

Answer (score 2):

change the following line in config.inc.php file

From :

```
$g_smtp_host        = 'smtp.gmail.com:465';
```

To :

```
$g_smtp_host        = 'smtp.gmail.com';
```

and try.

i had less stackoverflow reputation to comment your question so only posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove port from

```
$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com:465';
```

like

```
$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
```

and add port below as

```
$g_smtp_port = 465;
```

and select connection mode as ssl

```
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 30.05.2022 Google restrict login by Login and Password without 2-step auth. So when Testlink will attempt connect to smtp.gmail.com by login and password it will be errors like `SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)`

**Workaround is to use App Passwords**: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

When you generate app password paste it in `$g_smtp_password` parameter in `config.inc.php` file.